# JTextArea gives out weird text when adding something to it

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, jtextarea

Hey I’m working on a Selling class of a simple Java Swing GUI supermarket project. When I add the first item to the billingtxt, it lists them normally as if there is nothing wrong! But if I add more items, it will bring out weird text as shown in the image.
[First item works just fine but second will bring weird text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vm9U2.png)
This is the text Im talking about:

My code is shared underneath. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance:)

```
package supermarket1;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

/**
 *
 * @author patrickschnepf
 */
public class Selling1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Selling1
     */
    public Selling1() {
        initComponents();
        SelectSeller();
        
    }

    Connection Con = null;
Statement St = null;
ResultSet Rs = null;
   public void SelectSeller()
{
        try {
            Con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/SuperMarketdb1","User1","1234");
            St = Con.createStatement();
            Rs = St.executeQuery("Select * from User1.PRODUCTTBL");
            ProductTable.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(Rs));
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
   int PrId, newQty;
   public void update()
{
        newQty = AvailQty - Integer.valueOf(ProdQty.getText());
    try{
               Con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/SuperMarketdb1","User1","1234");
               String Query ="Update User1.PRODUCTTBL set PRODQUANTITY="+newQty+""+" where PRODID="+PrId;
               Statement Add = Con.createStatement();
               Add.executeUpdate(Query);
               SelectSeller();
               
           }catch(SQLException e){
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
} 
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        ProductTable = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        BillTxt = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        AddBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        ProdName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        ProdQty = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        ClearBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        EditBtn = new javax.swing.JButton();
        SummeLbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 153, 0));

        jLabel8.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 20)); // NOI18N
        jLabel8.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel8.setText("X");
        jLabel8.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jLabel8MouseClicked(evt);
            }
            public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jLabel8MouseEntered(evt);
            }
        });

        jPanel2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

        ProductTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        ProductTable.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        ProductTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {
                "ProdID", "Name", "Menge", "Preis", "Kategorie"
            }
        ));
        ProductTable.setRowHeight(25);
        ProductTable.setSelectionBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 102, 0));
        ProductTable.setSelectionForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        ProductTable.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                ProductTableMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(ProductTable);

        jLabel9.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel9.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 102, 0));
        jLabel9.setText("Wählen sie die zu Verkaufende Produkte aus:");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 20)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 102, 0));
        jLabel3.setText("Produkt Liste");

        BillTxt.setColumns(20);
        BillTxt.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        BillTxt.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(BillTxt);

        AddBtn.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        AddBtn.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 102, 0));
        AddBtn.setText("Zur Rechnung hinzufügen");
        AddBtn.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                AddBtnMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 102, 0));
        jLabel4.setText("Name:");

        ProdName.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        ProdName.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 102, 0));

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 102, 0));
        jLabel5.setText("Menge:");

        ProdQty.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        ProdQty.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 102, 0));

        ClearBtn.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        ClearBtn.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 102, 0));
        ClearBtn.setText("Zurücksetzen");
        ClearBtn.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                ClearBtnMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        ClearBtn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                ClearBtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        EditBtn.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        EditBtn.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 102, 0));
        EditBtn.setText("Drucken");
        EditBtn.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                EditBtnMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        SummeLbl.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        SummeLbl.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 102, 0));
        SummeLbl.setText("Summe: ");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(244, 244, 244)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(ProdQty, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 135, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(ProdName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 135, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(150, 150, 150)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 396, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 38, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel9)
                        .addGap(68, 68, 68))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(AddBtn)
                        .addGap(150, 150, 150)
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                .addGap(151, 151, 151))
                            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 396, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(SummeLbl)
                                        .addGap(159, 159, 159)))
                                .addGap(38, 38, 38))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(85, 85, 85)
                                .addComponent(EditBtn)
                                .addGap(63, 63, 63)
                                .addComponent(ClearBtn)
                                .addContainerGap())))))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(19, 19, 19)
                .addComponent(jLabel3)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jLabel9)
                .addGap(15, 15, 15)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 180, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(ProdName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel4))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(ProdQty, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5))))
                .addGap(17, 17, 17)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 178, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(AddBtn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 36, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(SummeLbl)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(EditBtn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 38, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(ClearBtn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 40, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
        );

        jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 20)); // NOI18N
        jLabel7.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel7.setText("Logout");
        jLabel7.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jLabel7MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial Black", 1, 20)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel1.setText("Kasse");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(342, 342, 342)
                .addComponent(jLabel8)
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(26, 26, 26)
                .addComponent(jLabel7)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel7)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel8)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(22, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        
    Double Uprice, ProdTot=0.0,GrdTot=0.0;
    int AvailQty;
    private void ProductTableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)ProductTable.getModel();
        int MyIndex = ProductTable.getSelectedRow();

        PrId = Integer.valueOf(model.getValueAt(MyIndex, 0).toString());
        AvailQty = Integer.valueOf(model.getValueAt(MyIndex, 2).toString());
        
        ProdName.setText(model.getValueAt(MyIndex, 1).toString());
        Uprice = Double.valueOf(model.getValueAt(MyIndex, 3).toString());
        
        
    }                                         
    int i = 0;
    private void AddBtnMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    
        if(ProdQty.getText().isEmpty() || ProdName.getText().isEmpty() )
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Fehlende Informationen");
        }
        else if(AvailQty <= Integer.valueOf(ProdQty.getText()))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Nicht genug auf Lager");
        }
        else{
            
            i++;
            ProdTot = Uprice * Double.valueOf(ProdQty.getText());
            GrdTot = GrdTot+ProdTot;
            if( i == 1)
            {
                BillTxt.setText(BillTxt.getText()+"============Tante Emma Laden============\n"+"Nummer  Produkt  Preis  Menge  Summe\n"+i+"        "+ProdName.getText()+"        "+Uprice+"        "+ProdQty.getText()+"        "+ProdTot+"\n\t");
            }else
            {
                BillTxt.setText(BillTxt.getText()+"    "+i+"               "+ProdName+"               "+Uprice+"               "+ProdQty.getText()+"               "+ProdTot+"\n");
            }
            SummeLbl.setText("Zu zahlen: "+GrdTot + " €");
            update();
        }
    }                                   

    private void ClearBtnMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        
        ProdName.setText("");
        BillTxt.setText("");
        ProdQty.setText("");
        SummeLbl.setText("Summe: ");
    }                                     

    private void ClearBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                        

    private void EditBtnMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        try{
            BillTxt.print();
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            
        }
        
    }                                    

    private void jLabel8MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        System.exit(0);
    }                                    

    private void jLabel8MouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        jLabel8.setForeground(Color.red);
    }                                    

    private void jLabel7MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        new Login().setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
    }                                    
    
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Selling1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Selling1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Selling1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Selling1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Selling1().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton AddBtn;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea BillTxt;
    private javax.swing.JButton ClearBtn;
    private javax.swing.JButton EditBtn;
    private javax.swing.JTextField ProdName;
    private javax.swing.JTextField ProdQty;
    private javax.swing.JTable ProductTable;
    private javax.swing.JLabel SummeLbl;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel9;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Ive tried looking for errors but there were non and

Answer (score 1):

You have an object named `ProdName` that is lying; it's not a name at all, it's a `JTextField` object. It isn't text, it's a field that can contain text. That field should be named `prodNameField` for some example (in java we `writeVariableNamesLikeThis` and `TypesLikeThis`. You're signing yourself up for a life of annoyance if you don't adjust your style, **all** java code is written like that).

In your code you have this line:

```
BillTxt.setText(BillTxt.getText()+"    "+i+"               "+ProdName+"               "+Uprice+"               "+ProdQty.getText()+"               "+ProdTot+"\n");
```

This calls `toString()` on ProdName and concatenates that to the rest of the strings in this statement. The toString of a JTextField is the 'strange text' you see. You want to [A] make that `ProdName.getText()`, and [B] you want to adjust all your variable names because the problem with them is that they are confusing, and this question proves that it has confused you. `prodQtyField`, `prodNameField`, etcetera.